# Check the color of a rectangle drawn on a HTML5 canvas and make sure not to draw a circle over it

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Lets say I draw a rectangle on the html canvas:

```
draw.rect(x, y, w, h, color); // color red
```

After I draw the rectangle I will draw a circle on the same canvas:

```
draw.circle(x, y, d, color); // color green
```

I have to randomly generate the coordinates for the circle.

*Both draw functions are inside a loop - set interval - and a clear canvas function.*

**I am wondering if there is a way to make sure I won't draw the circle over the rectangle.**

In a normal situation that would be easy, **just remember the last coordinates of the rectangle and choose different ones for the circle** - but for other reasons I cannot do it.

Would it be possible to check the canvas for the color of the rectangle which was drew on it, and make sure the circle will not be drawn over that color?

I know how to analyze the color of a background image, but I don't know if the above is possible.
For background images I use:

```
ctx.getImageData()
```

Comment: Will the color of the rectangle only appear where the rectangle has been drawn? That is, will other things with the same color as the rectangle be drawn on the canvas?

Comment: Yes, if the rectangle is red - no other elements with the color red will be drawn. This is why I am hoping there is a way. Image a white canvas with a red rectangle and a green circle - draw the green circle anywhere except the red

Comment: A way to have this to work even with other objects drawn is to use another temporary canvas :  use, as globalCompositeOperation,  'source-over' to draw the rect, then 'destination-over' to draw the circle. Then to copy that temporary canvas on the main. Much faster than get/putImageData, especially if you create the re-use the same temp canvas (which size's is : sum of sizes of rect+circle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always be able to store the last drawn coordinates.
At least by using a glval var. which you can make not-so ugly 
by using a namespace :

```
window.myApp = {};
myApp.lastDrawnRect = { x:-1, y:0, w:0, h:0 };
myApp.storeRect= function(x,y,w,h) {
             var rect = myApp.lastDrawnRect;
             rect.x = x; rect.y = y; rect.w = w;
}
```

and when you draw your rect you can store the coordinates :

```
raw.rect(x, y, w, h, color); // color red
myApp.storeRect(x,y,w,h);
```

You might want to store that the rectangle is not drawn by
taking the convention that x==-1  ===> rectangle cleared.

Then you can use that data when you draw your circle, with
classic boundary checking.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is drawn on the canvas is accessible using `getImageData`.
A canvas is a pixel matrix with drawing helpers attached.

Before drawing the circle you can `ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1)` and check if it's red.
You most probably have to check the pixels on the edge of the circle, not the center.
Start from the circle equation. 
It's been [discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155649/circle-coordinates-to-array-in-javascript).